# Javascript: Get only duplicate values from an array of objects based on several key value pairs (but not all)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've looked a pile of answers to *related* questions, but haven't found anything that directly handles this. Should be simple, but I'm drawing a blank.

If I have an array like this:

```
const items = [
{id: uuid-uuu, itemId: 110, nbr: 135, recordID: 222},
{id: uuid-www, itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
{id: uuid-xxx, itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
{id: uuid-yyy, itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 111},
{id: uuid-zzz, itemId: 112, nbr: 135, recordID: 222},
]
```

And I want to look at itemId, nbr, and recordID values, (but NOT id and other keys not included in this example) and find any objects where those are all the same, and return those unchanged duplicated objects (multiple) in a new array.

So in this case, I just want this as the result:

```
const duplicateItems = [
{id: uuid-www, itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
{id: uuid-xxx, itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
]
```

I don't want duplicates removed, I don't want only unique items - I only want the duplicate list.

Should I be using reduce, filter, Map, etc.?

Needs to be in plain JavaScript, but can use latest / ES6 functions.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple duplicates?

Comment: group by composite key (combination/concatenation of itemId+nbr+recordId) and for each key have an array and push to that array. now the arrays with more than 1 you need to filter out

Comment: @epascarello If there are multiple duplicates, they should all be returned.

Comment: @BeninCA, in the same array or like [[two duplicates], [more duplicates of a different composite key], ...]?

Comment: Yes, so there might be 100 items in the initial array, and there could be 30 duplicates / triplicates, etc. Basically, I just want to exclude the ones that do not have any other matches.

Comment: @BernardBorg Same array style and format as original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to generate a key based off the items you want. Easiest way is just using reduce. Reduce holds an object. You create an array with your key. You push in the objects into that array. After you are done with loop, filter your array for dupes and make it one array with flat.

```js
const items = [
  {id: 'uuid-uuu', itemId: 110, nbr: 135, recordID: 222},
  {id: 'uuid-www', itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
  {id: 'uuid-xxx', itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
  {id: 'uuid-yyy', itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 111},
  {id: 'uuid-zzz', itemId: 112, nbr: 135, recordID: 222},
];

const dupedItems = Object.values(items.reduce((acc, row) => {
    const {
      itemId,
      nbr,
      recordID
    } = row;
    // build up a key with the fields
    const key = `${itemId}*${nbr}*${recordID}`;
    // define an array or use the one that already exists
    acc[key] ??= [];
    // add the item to your array for this key
    acc[key].push(row)
    return acc;
  }, {})).filter(x => x.length > 1) // select only the arrays with more than one items
  .flat(); // reduce the 2D array into a 1D array

console.log(dupedItems);
```

Comment: exactly what i had in mind

Comment: Quite elegant. Thanks! I can see why I was having trouble with this. Also, I've never seen the ??= (null coalesce equal operator) used in JavaScript... a new tip besides!

Comment: Most people write it as `acc[key] = acc[key] || [];` or `if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];`. I do a lot of data transformations and will use them based on different transformation needs.

Answer (score 0):

**[NOTE: REQUIRES POLYFILLS]**

Could try something like this;

```js
const items = [
{id: "uuid-uuu", itemId: 110, nbr: 135, recordID: 222},
{id: "uuid-www", itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
{id: "uuid-xxx", itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 555},
{id: "uuid-yyy", itemId: 111, nbr: 134, recordID: 111},
{id: "uuid-zzz", itemId: 112, nbr: 135, recordID: 222},
];

let duplicateValues = [...Map.groupBy(items, item  => {
        return `${item.itemId}|${item.nbr}|${item.recordID}`;
}).entries()].filter(x => x[1].length > 1).map(x => x[1]).flat();

console.log(keys);
```

1. Group items by key (you can't use an object with the composite key for group by since the comparison isn't deep, so you can concatenate (the | is to divide the keys).
2. Get the entries and convert to array so you can use ES6 methods
3. Filter out groups with more than 1 value (contain duplicates)
4. Map to the value (since you don't need the key)
5. Flatten the result to get all duplicates of matching any composite key in the same array

https://jsfiddle.net/tk13nzhm/32/

Comment: need polyfills to use groupby

Comment: JSFiddle says Uncaught TypeError: Map.groupBy is not a function; not sure if you had a pollyfill for that setup. (Otherwise I can)